# Erro #26 ao enviar arquivo via curl Com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Olá,

Primeiramente desculpa se faltar algo ou se não estiver bem formatado a pergunta, minha primeira pergunta.

Bem, estou precisando enviar um arquivo CSV via CURL para uma API que realiza um cadastro, mas quando envio o arquivo me retorna o erro 26 do curl (Curl failed with error #26), no qual aponta erro de leitura.

Primeiro verifiquei o funcionamento da API pelo POSTMAN e está funcionando corretamente.

Tenho uma função na qual realiza o upload do arquivo no diretório `"./src/temp/"`, logo após o upload vem a função na qual realizo um POST via curl com o envio do arquivo.

Por via das duvidas realizei uma checagem temporária visual antes da execução para verificar se o arquivo existe e se consegue ler o arquivo, porém mesmo me retornando que existe e consegue ler o arquivo, ainda me retorna o erro do curl.

Segue código:

```
$file = "./src/temp/{$_FILES['arquive']['name']}";

if(file_exists($file)){
    echo "exite";
    if(fopen($file, "r")){
        echo " e conseguiu ler";
    }else{
        echo " e falhou ao ler";
    }
}else{
    echo "não existe";
}

try {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($ch === false) {
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    }

    $cfile = new CURLFile($file , $_FILES['arquive']['type'] , 'Arquivo');

    $params = [
        'arquive' => $cfile,
        'template' => $post['template'],
        'acao' => $post['type'],
        'segmentacao' => $post['segmentation'],
    ];

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $_FILES['arquive']['size'],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Basic ****:****",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;",
        ),
    ]);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($content === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf( 'Curl failed with error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Testei passar o arquivo com base em outras soluções que encontrei aqui, como:

  `...'arquive' => curl_create_file($file)...`

  `...'arquive' => "@".$file...`

E acabei deixando do jeito OO mesmo.

Passei um longo período pesquisando a solução mas infelizmente não consegui, refiz varias vezes adaptando a exemplos que encontrei aqui, mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas para deixar registrado e para consulta dos usuários, consegui resolver o problema.

Pensei direito no que estava fazendo, estava alocando o arquivo em uma pasta local e passando o caminho `$file` no primeiro parâmetro para a classe `CURLFile` para envio do mesmo, tudo dentro de uma mesma requisição.

```
$file = "./src/temp/{$_FILES['arquive']['name']}";

$cfile = new CURLFile($file , $_FILES['arquive']['type'] , 'Arquivo');
```

Passei a utilizar `$_FILES['arquive']['tmp_name']` que armazena o valor onde o arquivo fica temporariamente armazenado e funcionou

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['arquive']['tmp_name'] , $_FILES['arquive']['type'] , 'Arquivo');
```